# Create regex character set from string

Tags: python, regex, tokenize, python-re, string-interpolation

I have a string containing unique chars that I want to place inside regex char set.
For example "abc" -> r"[abc]".
I have a little bit more difficult case and tried to do something like that:

```py
symbols = "\n \"'\\(),.!-/"

re_str = "["
for s in symbols:
    re_str += s
re_str += "]"
```

But result isn't satisfying

```
[\n "\'\\(),.!-/]
```

The backslash before " disappeared, but the one appeared before '. Regex101 says that it is the wrong syntax for python.

Also, it doesn't work if the string contains special re chars like \d \s.

What is the best way to do such an operation?

Comment: Does declaring symbols as a raw string have the effect you want - i.e. r"\n \"'\\(),.!-/"?
You show the unacceptable result but not what you're actually hoping for

Comment: @AndyKnight no, it works even worse. Because \n is interpreted as \ and n separately

Comment: Does the result work, though? Half the problem will be interpreting the string as printed out (you don't say how you print it out)

Comment: For example, in the original string, there is no \ before the "

Comment: Please show what the output should look like

Comment: @sabik seems like the real problem is that I don't know the difference between raw string and just string) also the same problem with print

Comment: Yeah; there are too many places in this question where the \ is used as an escape; in the string you type in, in the regex itself, in output; even on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```py
symbols = r"\n \"'\\(),.!-/"
re_str = "[" + symbols + "]"
```

Tested it the following way:

```py
print(re.match(re_str, "\n"))
print(re.match(re_str, "\""))
print(re.match(re_str, "\\"))
print(re.match(re_str, "\'"))
print(re.match(re_str, "("))
print(re.match(re_str, ")"))
...
```

Each of these have returned a match object with the correct span

In contrast, without the `r` raw string modifier, it doesn't match `\\`.